# how to implement comparator in java?

Tags: java, collections, set

`Stop(Id, Name)` is a java class, and i want to store these stop objects in a `java.util.Set` and those objects should be sorted according to the `Id` of `Stop`.
this is my comparator

```
public class StopsComparator implements Comparator{

    @Override
    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Stop stop1 = (Stop)o1;
        Stop stop2 = (Stop)o2;

        return stop1.getStopId().compareTo(stop2.getStopId());
    }
}


 private Set<Stop> stops = new TreeSet<Stop>(new StopsComparator());
```

but its not giving correct result?

Comment: What do you mean by 'its not giving correct result?' Does the order get messed up? Does it throw exceptions? Does the world end? Did Santa get replaced by a bunny? Please provide full details (input data, call add elements to set, result/call stack, photo of bunny and sketch of expected santa.

Comment: its not giving the correct order. How to do this do i need to implement equals and hashcode method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does Stop implement an equals method that works on the same field as your comparator? If not then that will lead to problems. You also might want to switch to have your object implement Comparable (although that wouldn't fix the problem you're seeing).

Once you implement an `equals()` method, then you should also implement a `hashCode()` method that works on the same field.

[Findbugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/) would have probably told you these things. Its extremely useful.

Answer (score 1):

The following code works for me -

```
public class Stop {

    private Long id;
    private String name;

    public Stop(Long id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Stop{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                '}';
    }

    private static class StopComparator implements Comparator<Stop> {


        public int compare(Stop o1, Stop o2) {
            return o1.getId().compareTo(o2.getId());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<Stop> set = new TreeSet<Stop>(new StopComparator());
        set.add(new Stop(102L, "name102"));
        set.add(new Stop(66L, "name66"));
        set.add(new Stop(72L, "name72"));
        System.out.println(set);
    }
}
```

prints -

> [Stop{id=66, name='name66'}, Stop{id=72, name='name72'}, Stop{id=102,
>   name='name102'}]

Ofc you need to implement `equals` and `hashcode` so that class behaves consistently in each `Set` implementation, but for `TreeSet` this should work as is since `TreeSet` relies on `compareTo` method while performing `add`, `remove` or `contains` operations (instead of `equals` like `HashSet`).

Comment: TreeSet relies on compareTo method while performing put, remove or contains operations (instead of equals like HashSet). what exactly is this.

Comment: Set interface contract says it should use `equals` to determine equality, but `TreeSet` have little optimization and uses `compareTo` to determine equality and not `equlas`, so above example should work without implementing `equlas` and `hashcode` in Stop class.

Answer (score 0):

This is from the [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) docs:

> The ordering imposed by a comparator c on a set of elements S is said to be consistent with equals if and only if c.compare(e1, e2)==0 has the same boolean value as e1.equals(e2) for every e1 and e2 in S.
>
> Caution should be exercised when using a comparator capable of imposing an ordering inconsistent with equals to order a sorted set (or sorted map). Suppose a sorted set (or sorted map) with an explicit comparator c is used with elements (or keys) drawn from a set S. If the ordering imposed by c on S is inconsistent with equals, the sorted set (or sorted map) will behave "strangely." In particular the sorted set (or sorted map) will violate the general contract for set (or map), which is defined in terms of equals.

I would recommend to try implementing `equals` and `hashCode`.